# What is the right way to log to app insights?

Tags: java, azure, docker, azure-application-insights

I have been searching this for a while. Im surprised that I don't get a clear answer to my question. I am trying to log to application insights. My app is written in java running in a docker container in AKS on azure. It is not clear to me if I have to use the app-insights agent for this situation or if I should just configure a log4j logger to log to app-insights. What is the right way to do logging for a java app in a docker container running in AKS on azure? With or without app-insights agent?

Comment: Did you you read [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/azure-monitor/app/java-get-started) which clearly says 'The recommended approach to monitor Java applications is to use the auto-instrumentation without changing the code. Please follow the guidelines for [Codeless monitoring](https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/azure-monitor/app/java-in-process-agent)'.

Comment: I have read similar things. I have also read that the agent is only for on prem and not needed when running in a sure which confused me

Comment: Would you mind sharing any reference/link?

Comment: @KrishnenduGhosh-MSFT am trying to find the docs. Please hold. Just curious, why would i want codeless monitoring? I already have my log4j stuff setup everywhere? Is that the entire use case for using the agent? Why would somebody choose to not use the agent?

Comment: @KrishnenduGhosh-MSFT. I found the doc. When I look at it again, I think i misunderstood. There is link that is 'on premis server deployments' and then it links to application insights docs. I was assuming when I clicked on that the first time because of the wording that the agent is for on prem. I see when clicking on the link after that it recommends agent as well. I would still appreciate a comment to the above question if you have time. Thank you. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/monitor-performance-live-website-now

Comment: Also one more thing. If i were to start a new application without logging and chose to use the agent. Would i just add log4j or telemetry for the stuff that the automatic logging is not picking up? What are the use cases for each? Thanks.